# Files in Sharepoint folder display incorrectly

Tags: explorer, office-2016

The files that I've synced to my local folder are displaying with a white paper icon in the lower left corner as seen below.

[image: Image 1]

When in detail view, the white paper covers up almost the entire icon so I can barely see what file type it is.

[image: Image 2]

Has anyone seen this before or know how to get my icons back to displaying properly?

I have Office 2016 installed.

Comment: Looks to me like your "Shortcut arrow" icon is corrupted or missing. This could be because of issues with your desktop user profile. Is this happening just for you or others also?

Answer (score 0):

The comment Ransher Singh posted was correct and led me to the answer. My shortcut arrow icons weren't working properly, which I validated by logging in to my local admin account on this computer and didn't see the issue occurring.

Following this guide https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8974-shortcut-arrow-icon-change-remove-restore-windows-10-a.html#option2 and then killing explorer.exe and restarting it resolved my issue.